# Instagram Feed Jquery Plugin

Tags: instagram, feed, instafeedjs

I would like to add your Instagram feed to my website. I post pictures on Instagram here. How Can I do this. https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ at this address, a new client I have created. I'm doing but something is missing. I couldn't do with Instafeed.

Answer (score 0):

i guess u stuck with the place about access token.. u should approve Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication..

If you are building an app that does not have a server component (a purely javascript app, for instance), you will notice that it is impossible to complete step three above to receive your access_token without also having to store the secret on the client. You should never pass or store your client_id secret onto a client. For these situations there is the Implicit Authentication Flow.

Step One: Direct your user to our authorization URL

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token
At this point, we present the user with a login screen and then a confirmation screen where they grant your app’s access to their Instagram data. Note that unlike the explicit flow the response type here is “token”.

Step Two: Receive the access_token via the URL fragment

Once the user has authenticated and then authorized your application, Instagram redirects them to your redirect_uri with the access_token in the url fragment. It will look like this:

http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
Simply grab the access_token off the URL fragment and you’re good to go. If the user chooses not to authorize your application, you’ll receive the same error response as in the explicit flow